# extract all TD or TH columns

Tags: java, jsoup

Currently I extract all the columns in the row of a table using:

```
my_element_collection = row.select("td"))
```

But in some of the documents I'm processing, some columns are created using `th` instead of `td`. Is there a way to select all "th" *and* "td" elements using jsoup's selector? (If this were a regexp, I imagine it would be something like `th|td` but I'm struggling to find an answer in the docs...)

Comment: It is well documented: (1) http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html -> Combinators -> `E, F, G` all matching elements E, F, or G (2) http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax -> Selector combinations -> "`el, el, el`: group multiple selectors, find unique elements that match any of the selectors;"

Comment: @Pshemo thanks, in retrospect it's clearly in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
my_element_collection = row.select("td,th")
```

Here is live sample: http://try.jsoup.org/~31-SUI1dXuWbSFK8ZPhQ5eqozTI